# angularjs-1.2.14.js:9509 TypeError: Cannot read property 'put' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, cookiestore

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to store a value in cookieStore but am getting below error.

```
angularjs-1.2.14.js:9509 TypeError: Cannot read property 'put' of undefined
```

**My code :**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

var ivm = ivm || {};

angular
    .module('ivm', ['ivml.chart', 'ngCookies'])
    .run(run);

run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];
    function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.xaxis_length = $cookieStore.get('xaxis_length') || {};
    }

var ivm = ivm || {};
ivm.visualElements = ivm.visualElements || {};

ivm.visualElements.Bars = function Bars(chartController, barController, $timeout, $cookieStore, $rootScope) {

    var Bars = {
        elements: {
            chartController: chartController,
            barController: barController,
            $timeout: $timeout,
            xscale: null,
            yscale: null,
            svg_g: null,
            frame: null,
            index: -1
        },
        attributes: {
            fill: "black", //@i fill color of the bar
            fillOpacity: 1, //@i fill opacity of bar
            stroke: null, //@i color of the bar's outline
            strokeWidth: 1, //@i stroke width of the bar's line
            strokeOpacity: 1,  //@i opacity of the bar's outline
            thickness: 5 //@i the bar's thickness (size parallel to the dependent dimension)
        },
        accessors: {
            data: [], //@ir javascript object to plot
            positionFunction: null,//@ir accessor for the bar's  position on the nominal axis
            valueFunction: null //@ir accessor for the the bar's value (size and direction)

        },
        events: {
            mouseOverE: null, //@e mouse over event
            mouseOutE: null, //@e mouse out event
            clickE: null    //@e mouse click event
        }

    }

    var xaxis_length = "0";
    console.log(xaxis_length);
    $cookieStore.put('xaxis_length',xaxis_length);
```

I am getting error at the above line that `put` can't read.

Where I have done the mistake? There are many functions in my code and I have pasted only one function where am getting error.

Comment: Where and how do you call `ivm.visualElements.Bars`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$inject` property to your controller as well as you did with `run` block

```
ivm.visualElements.Bars.$inject 
 = ['chartController', 'barController', '$timeout', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope'];
```